# How can I calculate the percentage of cases per two groups?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
subject <- c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3), rep("C",3), rep("D",3))
item <- c(1:3, 1,4,5,1,2,6,3,4,7)
group <- c(rep("pre",6), rep("post",6))

initialdf <- data.frame(subject,item,group)
```

and I would like to get the percentage of subjects who chose each item, in order to get the following dataframe:

```
item2 <- c(rep(1:7,2))
group2 <- c(rep("pre",7),rep("post",7))
percent <- c(100,rep(50,4),rep(0,2),rep(50,4),0,rep(50,2))

finaldf <- data.frame(item2,group2,percent)
```

I have tried the following groupings, but can't seem the get the `finaldf` I'm looking for:

1. `group_by(subject)%>%`
2. `group_by(group)%>%`
3. `group_by(subject,group)%>%`
4. `group_by(group,subject)%>%`
5. `group_by(group,item)%>%`
6. `group_by(item,group)%>%`
7. `group_by(item,subject)%>%`
8. `group_by(subject,item)%>%`

(Each time I grouped them differently, I calculated the percentage as follows, changing the type of grouping):

```
initialdf%>%
  group_by(subject)%>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))%>%
  mutate(Percent = freq*100)
```

I would really appreciate any feedback on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Never use `cbind()` inside `data.frame` when you have different data types. The `cbind()` will turn everything into a matrix first and a matrix can only have one data type so you are turning all your numeric values into strings. Just use `initialdf 
 <- data.frame(subject,item,group)`

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to `group_by` different columns to generate the `subject` count per `group`, then do the `reframe` with grouping of `item` and `group`. Finally, use `complete` to fill in missing entries with zero.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

initialdf %>% 
  mutate(nsub = n_distinct(subject, group), .by = group) %>% 
  reframe(percent = n()/nsub, .by = c(item, group)) %>% 
  distinct_all() %>% 
  complete(item, group, fill = list(percent = 0))

# A tibble: 14 × 3
   item  group percent
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 1     post      0.5
 2 1     pre       1  
 3 2     post      0.5
 4 2     pre       0.5
 5 3     post      0.5
 6 3     pre       0.5
 7 4     post      0.5
 8 4     pre       0.5
 9 5     post      0  
10 5     pre       0.5
11 6     post      0.5
12 6     pre       0  
13 7     post      0.5
14 7     pre       0
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I hadn't used reframe or complete before, they work great.